# wkhtmltopdf/wicked_pdf : some external pictures are not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to export a page in my rails app to a pdf using wkhtmltopdf/wickedpdf (both the latest version, so is rails). However, external images from facebook (obviously with an absolute url) are not displayed : I got the classic empty box with a '?' when pictures are missing. The HTML version is just fine.

I tried with other pictures from other sources, and it worked as expected. Only fb pictures are causing troubles. However I absolutely need those.

Any ideas? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it looks like I was using a bad version of wkhtmltopdf. Had to try several before getting to the right, [this](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-OS-X.i368&can=2&q=) is the one that did the trick for me.

@Hoang's answer is another possible solution.

Comment: Also, there was an issue with libssl on 0.12.4 and below which prevented image URLs using `https` to be rendered. Upgrade to 0.12.5 and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You should download the image into the app and use absolute path for image in pdf template, like

```
"#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/path-to-fb-image}"
```